# How can I find the last visible <td> in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, html-table

I am using a table with one row and several `<td>`s inside it and am using hide/show on `td`s. Every `td` has a unique id.

Is there any way to recognize the last visible td from that table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty trivial with jQuery

```
$('td:visible:last')
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SUJV/)

Comment: That's great, but his tags indicate he is using extJs.

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, I guess it should be something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagname('td');
for (var i = 0 ; i < els.length ; i++)
  if (els[i].style && els[i].style.display != 'none')
    last = els[i];
```